# Linux - Splash screen for Java application

Tags: java, splash-screen

On Windows I use Exe4J to start my Java Application. This has the following advantages:

- Splashscreen which shows before Java starts
- Possibility to update a Label on the splash screen during the startup, until the application is folly loaded ("Initializing Flux compensator","Reordering high nibbles", etc.)

Now I want to implement this on Linux. I start my App with a Shell script, but would love an easy way to show some kind of splash GUI with a label on it, which I can update from my shell script during startup.

Is there an easy way to fire up a minimal GUI from a shell script, and to update the label in it from the shell script, without having to compile a separate executable for it for linux (and maybe even Mac OS X)?

PS: I don't want to use the Java build in splash screen because of the Label which has to be updated dynamically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard Java 1.6+ solution for screen splash does support custom drawing on the splash [Screensplash Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html).

Here is an example for a splash controller, which has a main method -- run it with a splash parameter to see the result.

```
package somepackage;
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.SplashScreen;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

public class SplashController implements ActionListener {
    private static final int X = 20, W = 300;
    private static final int TEXT_H = 10, BAR_H = 10;

    private int textY, barY;
    private int barPos = 0;

    private final SplashScreen splash;
    private Graphics2D graph;

    public SplashController(final int msgXOffset, final int msgYOffset) {
    splash = SplashScreen.getSplashScreen();
    if (splash == null) {
         System.out.println("Error: no splash image specified on the command line");
         return;
    }

   // compute base positions for text and progress bar
   final Dimension splashSize = splash.getSize();
   textY = splashSize.height - msgYOffset;
   barY = splashSize.height - msgYOffset;

   graph = splash.createGraphics();
   //timer.start();
}

public SplashController() {
    this(30, 30);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
    drawSplashProgress(msg);
}

public void closeSplash() {
    if (splash != null) {
        splash.close();
    }
}

private String msg;

public void drawSplashProgress(final String msg) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            SplashController.this.msg = msg;
            graph.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,                              RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
            graph.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            graph.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            graph.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);

            // clear what we don't need from previous state
            graph.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Clear);

            final FontMetrics fm = graph.getFontMetrics();
            final Rectangle2D textsize = fm.getStringBounds(msg, graph);

            graph.fillRect(X, textY - 1, W, (int) textsize.getHeight() + 5);
            if (barPos == 0) {
                graph.fillRect(X - 3, barY, W + 10, BAR_H);
            }

            // draw new state
            graph.setPaintMode();

            // draw message
            graph.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            graph.drawString(msg, X, textY + TEXT_H);
            try {
                splash.update();
            } catch (final IllegalStateException e) {
               // can be ignored
            }
        }
     });
}

public static void main(final String args[]) throws Exception {
    final SplashController test = new SplashController();
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
       test.drawSplashProgress("Progress step number " + i);
       Thread.sleep(250);
    }
    test.closeSplash();
}  
}
```

Comment: +1 Oh, i didn't know about this solution yet. Could really be a solution to my problem. I will investigate...

Answer (score 1):

The Eclipse launcher supports this functionality on all platforms, but moving to SWT may be going too far? There are details [here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseRCP/article.html#product_splash).

Comment: I use SWT anyway, so that would be no problem! I didn't know I could configure the Eclipse launcher to do exactly this!

Answer (score 0):

You could use Python (or some other scripting language that exposes GUI functionality) from your script.

http://docs.python.org/faq/gui.html

Comment: okey, but I don't want to learn Python, or TCL, or any new language for this, and I don't want to add a python dependency to my program, also.